# Receiving multiple function outputs in one line

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have multiple functions:

```
type = {'a', 'b', ..., 'z'}
f={}
f['a'] = some func_a...
f['b'] = some func_b...
...
f['z'] = some func_z...
```

Now I want to get the outputs of them

```
output = {}
for t in type:
    output[t] = f[t](input)
```

I wonder if there is any way that we can do this in one line using a loop in a different way, like

```
[output[t] for t in type] = [f[t](input) for t in type]
```

Of course, this does not work. So would there be any valid way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want a [*dictionary comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). It works just like a list comprehension, but instead of a single expression to form the values, you get to provide two expressions to generate both a key and a value:

```
output = {t: f[t](input) for t in type}
```

The dict comprehension produces a new dictionary object; there is no need or use for an initial `output = {}` line.

I'd just iterate over the items of `f`, as it already has the keys we need:

```
output = {t: func(input) for t, func in f.items()}
```

As a side note, instead of using separate assignments for all your `f` functions, just use a single dictionary definition:

```
f = {
    'a': some_func_a,
    'b': some_func_b,
    # ...
    'z': some_func_z,
}
```

`type` is not a great name for a variable, either, as that masks the [built-in function you may sometimes want to use](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type). You don't need to create that set separately, as iteration over `f` would give you the same keys, or you can use `set(f)` to create a set copy, or `f.keys()`, to get a [dictionary view object over the keys of `f`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects), which acts just like a set but is 'live' in that changes to `f` are reflected in it.